# Laravel Default Registration Select box value not saving in Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

In Laravel I created a select box in my default registration but the value is not saving in the database.

here is my code

AuthController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'role' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
      return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'role' => $data['role'],
    ]);
}
}
```

register.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('role') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Role</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {{ Form::select('role', array('Internal' => 'Internal', 'Local' => 'Local', 'International' => 'International'), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }} 
                                @if ($errors->has('role'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('role') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Can someone please tell me what is my mistake and what to change. Thanks!

Comment: Can you retrieve the select box value on $validator function?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar what do you mean?

Comment: I'm asking when dd($data) on your validator function on your AuthController can you the select box value being passed?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar no value is being passed

Comment: So only name, email and password is being passed? Are you sure the select tag is within the form tag?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar yes only the name, email and password is being passed. Yes its within the form tag.

Comment: Strange, could you please upload the register.blade.php file here?

Comment: I'll edit the code above with the full register.balde.php

Comment: You have used Laravel HTML Form collective package?

Comment: I'm getting the value for role as Internal on validator function?